# While running PHP in XAMPP server in Windows 7, I am getting the error "undefined variable _SESSION"

Tags: php

I am running an php website in xaamp server and while running i am getting this error, what does it means?  and how do i solve this?

> Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\Movie\admin.php on line 56

Comment: where is your code? what we check? where we get line 56?

Comment: you probably just forgot to use the dolar sign `$_SESSION['........`

Comment: if there was no `$` it would say undefined constant, right?

Comment: This is the code of the body "
</div>
<center>
  <div class="content" style="background-image:url(); height:427px; color: #FFF;">
 <p align="right"><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\web\Movie\admin.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\Movie\admin.php:58
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\web\Movie\admin.php</b> on line <b>58</b><br />"

Comment: yep.. https://3v4l.org/mSnAa

Comment: @Pamblam you're definetely right! It would say undefined variable if you do a echo $_SESSION['foo']; without session_start(); (just checked ahahah)

Comment: Actually i have given task to identify bugs and vulnerabilities in the code, but i dont know much about php. So please help me in making the report that what is the actual error?

Answer (score 2):

It most likely means you need to add `session_start();` to the very top of your php page.

Answer (score 2):

It means you are referencing the `_SESSION` variable without declaring it anywhere. Go to line 56 in your `admin.php` file to locate the reference. Once you find the reference you can then decide where to place the `session_start()` function call in your code to initialize `_SESSION`

For more info on session variables and `_SESSION` visit the `PHP` documentation page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: `session_start()` **must** be placed before any headers are uotput, for this reason it's generally good practive to put it at the top.